# OpenCV: filter by color in image

Tags: python, opencv, filtering

How can you display only a single color from a RGB image with OpenCV in python ?
The idea is to be able to print the image in a grey scale corresponding to the intensity of a certain color in the RGB spectrum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either use `split`:

```
blue, green, red = cv2.split(img)
```

Or, as this is a costly operation in terms of time and you only need one of the channles (for instance, red) you can directly slice the original image like as follows:

```
red = img[:,:,2]
```

Which will return a greyscaled image where the brighter pixels are the ones that have higher red values in the original image.

Hope this helped!

Comment: I planned to make this a self answered question, however, I feel that yours is even better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
# import usefull libraries
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Set global parameters
RED = 0
GREEN = 1
BLUE = 2

# Load the image
img_color = cv2.imread("fruits.jpg", flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

# Filter the image by desired color
img_color_filtered = np.asarray([y[RED] for x in img_color for y in x]).reshape((img_color.shape[:2]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img = Image.open(f"./smoke/first/mistake_cat" + ".png")
data = np.array(img)
red, green, blue, alpha = data.T  # Трансформируем матрицу и распаковываем
img_red = Image.fromarray(red)
img_green = Image.fromarray(green)
img_blue = Image.fromarray(blue)
img_alpha = Image.fromarray(alpha)
```